# How do I merge several 2D arrays into a single 2D array (list) in a box-like manner in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, image-processing

Say I have 9 2D arrays in the following format:

```
A1 = [[ a1, b1, c1 ],
      [ d1, e1, f1 ],
      [ g1, h1, i1 ]]

A2 = [[ a2, b2, c2 ],
      [ d2, e2, f2 ],
      [ g2, h2, i2 ]] 
.....
A9 = [[ a9, b9, c9 ],
      [ d9, e9, f9 ],
      [ g9, h9, i9 ]]
```

and I want to concatenate them to get a 2D array like this:

```
A = [B1, B2, B3]
```

where

```
B1 = np.concatenate((A1,A2, A3),axis=1) 
B2 = np.concatenate((A4,A5, A6),axis=1) 
B3 = np.concatenate((A7,A8, A9),axis=1)
```

I will have N arrays in my case and I calculate the value of N like so:

```
img = Image.open(file_name)
img_width, img_height = img.size

tile_height = int(input('Enter the height of tile:'))
tile_width = int(input('Enter the width of tile:'))

N = (img_height//tile_height)*(img_width//tile_width)

# **The image will be broken down into n tiles of size tile_width x tile_height**

for i in range(img_height//tile_height):
    for j in range(img_width//tile_width):
         box = (j*width, i*height, (j+1)*width, (i+1)*height)
         img.crop(box)
         ...
```

So essentially, I had an image that was broken down into N tiles and after some processing, I have these image tile data stored as numpy arrays and I want to concatenate/merge them into a single 2D numpy array in the same orientation as the original image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a perfect use case for [bmat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html)

**Edit: How to use bmat**

bmat accepts as the first argument a matrix of blocks.

```
[[A11, A12, ..., A1n]
 [A21, A22, ..., A2n]
 ...
 [Am1, Am2, ..., Amn]]
```

And is not limited to the 9 submatrices case, it was a coincidence that in the `bmat` documentation their example is the same size as the example in your question.

```py
import numpy as np;
mats = []
for i in range(10):
    mats.append(np.ones((4, 2)) * i);
np.bmat([mats[:5], mats[5:]])
```

Gives

```txt
matrix([[0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 4., 4.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 4., 4.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 4., 4.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3., 3., 4., 4.],
        [5., 5., 6., 6., 7., 7., 8., 8., 9., 9.],
        [5., 5., 6., 6., 7., 7., 8., 8., 9., 9.],
        [5., 5., 6., 6., 7., 7., 8., 8., 9., 9.],
        [5., 5., 6., 6., 7., 7., 8., 8., 9., 9.]])
```

Comment: yes, bmat is good but in my scenario, while I have the numpy arrays ready, I wouldn't always get 9. I might get even 10,11,12..., depending on the original image's dimensions. There could be 5x2 tiles or 3x3 tiles or 3x4 tiles. So in that scenario, how can I use bmat?

Comment: Added an example to the answer.